# Is "aws S3 cp" command Atomic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

Given, `s3://my/key/` is source folder and `/home/folder/` is target folder. We've several objects to copy and the object size varies b/w 5 KB to 300 MB.

I need to run below commands from multiple threads. For ex:

`aws s3 cp s3://my/key/ /home/folder/`

We've got following queries:

1. Is `aws s3 cp` operation atomic or thread safe ?
2. Is this still atomic with `--recursive` and `multi-part` upload option ?

Thanks in advance, looking for your thoughts and help

Comment: @Marcin, yes, if something is atomic then it is thread-safe, however, from the question context: say for ex: we have a number of objects to copy, what will happen if the node fails in between while copy is progress,?

Comment: When you use the term 'atomic' here, what exactly is it that you expect this to mean in the context of S3 operations?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html#ConsistencyModel), only actions on *single* key are atomic.

So copy of single key to different folder is atomic.

So:

1. It's atomic only if it's for single key
2. `--recursive` is not atomic, because it's not for single key. It will be executed for several keys. `multi-part` should be also atomic, for single part.

Comment: Thanks @Justinas, I got it, but is `multi-part` option also 'atomic' considering all the parts together? any document reference or thoughts on the same, ?

Comment: what would happen if a node fails while `aws s3 cp` operation along with `multi-part` option is still in progress ? please suggest

Comment: As definition of _atomic_ suggest - whole process of multi-part upload is not possible to be atomic. On failure you should restart upload

Comment: A multipart object will only appear in the bucket when the upload is complete.  It should be noted:  If the upload fails, the multipart parts will remain in storage, though not visible in the bucket, it's generally recommended to add a lifecycle rule to remove old multipart uploads after some number of days.